# JavaScript: how to stop an audio on autoplay by keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, audio, autoplay, pause

I want to know how to stop an audio that is set to "autoplay" using the X key on the keyboard. I have tried in a couple of method but it doesn't work.
That's my code:

JavaScript:

```js
var source = "audio/homepage_benvenuto.mp3";
        var audio = document.createElement("audio");
        audio.autoplay = true;
        audio.load()
        audio.addEventListener("load", function() 
        { 
                audio.play();
        }, true);
        audio.src = source;

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
        function checkKeyPressed(e) 
        {
if (e.keyCode == "88") // 88 = X: interrompe audio in corso
            {
                player.pause();
                player.currentTime = 0;
                document.getElementById('audioA').pause();
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the "X keyboard"?

Comment: He means the 'X' key.